# How to change child text only with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a piece html code like this:

```
<div><span>span_text</span>div_text</div>
```

I want to change 'div_text' with jQuery, tried with $.text('changed_div_text') but failed, result like this which is not what I want.

```
let tmpl = '<div><span>span_text</span>div_text</div>'
let $ = cheerio(tmpl)

console.log($.text()) // span_textdiv_text
$.text('changed_div_text')
console.log($.text()) // changed_div_text
```

As you can see, text() function will change inner text also, hope someone know a way to solve this problem, thanks!

Comment: Could you put another span around that text? Then it would be easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't offer a lot of methods that act directly on text nodes. You can use `contents` to find all child nodes (including text nodes), and you can use `filter` to find *only* text nodes, and then you can modify their `nodeValue` to change their text. Example:

```js
// Get just the text nodes
var textNodes = $("#target").contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE;
});

// In this case, I just replace the text with "Index n" where n is the index
textNodes.each(function(index) {
  this.nodeValue = "Index " + index;
});
```

```html
<div id="target"><span>span_text</span>div_text</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to know the text `div_text` is the childNode of div,and it is kind of textNode

```
var div=document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML='<div><span>span_text</span>div_text</div>';
div.childNodes[0].childNodes[1].textContent='test';
console.log(div.innerHTML);//<div><span>span_text</span>test</div>
```

if you want to change the text,you can change the value of the textNode,for example,change the `textContent` ,`innerText` or `innerHTML`,,,

Answer (score 0):

your html code is `<div><span>span_text</span>div_text</div>`

for your understanding I am assuming a button with id btn. clicking this button the text will be changed

button code `<button id="btn">change</button>`

now if you want to change all the child text of the div then the below code will work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("div > span").text("changed_div_text");
    });
});
```

now if you only want to change the last child of the div then the code is below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $("div > span:last-child").text("changed_div_text");
    });
});
```

hope it will solve your issue